# Convert a class that has a string property into another class with typed property value

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

Having the following classes:

```
public class DeviceParameter
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public Guid DeviceId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

A **device** can have a lot of **parameters**, of different types, but they are all stored in the database as strings.

```
public abstract class DeviceValueTypedParameter<TValue>
{
    public string CodeName { get; }

    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    public Guid DeviceId { get; set; }

    public DeviceValueTypedParameter(string codeName)
    {
        this.CodeName = codeName;
    }
}
```

**DeviceValueTypedParameter** is an abstraction, to have a **typed value** (*TValue*) **used on C#** of the parameter value, instead of using the string that we get from the database. There is no heritance between DeviceValueTypedDeviceParameter and DeviceParameter because I want to make the conversion from TValue to string by composition.

```
public class ArmingStatusParameter : DeviceValueTypedParameter<ArmingStatuses>
{
    public const string CODE_NAME = "ArmingStatus";

    public ArmingStatusParameter() : base(CODE_NAME)
    {
    }
}

public enum ArmingStatuses
{
    Unknown,
    Armed,
    Disarmed,
}
```

**ArmingStatusParameter** is an example of a typed Parameter that can exist, where the value is an Enum of ArmingStatuses. Other types that can exist are DateTimes, int32, double, etc.

I've already accomplished the conversion from Typed value to string, but now I'm struggling how to properly do the conversion from string to Typed value.

Tried different approaches:

1. Implicit or Explicit conversion
2. Extension method
3. Converter classes for each type that exists
4. Generic converter class based on TValue type

Option 1: is easy to implement, but violates the POCO of
ArmingStatusParameter. People can forget to implement the implicit/explicit operators and errors will only happen at compile time.

Option 2: violates the Interface segregation principle (ISP), since is needed to access directly the conversion.

Option 3: it works, but people will have to create a lot of classes and the code will be too verbose. For each different parameter, is needed to instance a new {X}TypedParameterConverter.

Option 4: **seems the best option, but I am having troubles "in making it work"**

I was thinking about something like this:

```
public interface IDeviceValueTypedParameterConverter
{
    bool TryConvert<T, TValue>(DeviceParameter deviceParameter, 
        DeviceValueTypedParameter<TValue> deviceValueTypedParameter)
        where T : DeviceValueTypedParameter<TValue>;
}

public class DeviceValueTypedParameterConverter : IDeviceValueTypedParameterConverter
{
    public bool TryConvert<T, TValue>(DeviceParameter inputParameter, 
            DeviceValueTypedParameter<TValue> outputParameter)
            where T : DeviceValueTypedParameter<TValue>
    {
        bool result = true;
        if (inputParameter == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException($"DeviceValueTypedParameter:'{typeof(T)}' must be initialized first");
        }

        if (inputParameter.Value is int)
        {
            result = int.TryParse(inputParameter.Value, out int temp);
            outputParameter.Value = (TValue)temp;
        }
        else if (inputParameter.Value is Enum)
        {
            // some other code to convert the Enum's
        }
        // more else ifs one for each type 
        // (...)
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }
        outputParameter.DeviceId = inputParameter.DeviceId;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Issues:

- All the Ifs gives me a warning saying: "The given expression is never of the provided".
- Can't make the cast (TValue). It says can't convert int to TValue. The only solution is creating value via reflection?

Comment: I think you're looking for the ISerializable interface. Implement this in your classes that need to be stored as text.

Comment: Only the Property Value is stored on a string, and I have no issues on the conversion to a string, the question is to how to convert from DeviceParameter to a DeviceValueTypedParameter<TValue> when I retrieve this value from the database. They are not the same class, can't use serialization here.

Comment: I'd rethink what you're trying to do so that you're not even trying to solve this problem. It sounds like you've already identified some of the issues with where it leads. Can you rethink this so that it *is* serializable?

Comment: `DeviceParameter.Value` must always be string, so I don't see how your `is` tests could ever work? Also, don't you need `out` on your out parameter? Does the `DeviceParameter.Key` give you a hint about the type of `Value`?

Comment: @ScottHannen since I can't change the database or how the way values were stored on the database, I'm don't see how to use serialization in this case, and even so, It didn't solve all the issues, only the one regarding conversion of TValue.

Comment: @NetMage Key is the same as CodeName. One of the mistakes was using inputParameter, instead of outputParameter to get the info about the type :(. Regarding the other issue about converting, on C# Convert.ChangeType is the only? I thought that was a reflection but now I see is from the system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to make this work - I am not sure if it violates some details you did not explain (or did explain). Since `out` parameters can't use polymorphism, I created an interface to represent the common functions across the typed parameter base class. Since there are no static virtual methods, I used object methods and created a result object that will is used if the conversion is possible.

I see no reason for the conversion method to have multiple instances or need an interface, so I created it as a single static method. I used an `enum` to capture the type of conversion needed for the parameter accessible from the passed in type, and had to do a tricky conversion through `object` to handle assignment to the `out` parameter value field, since C# has no type switching capability for assignments. Note this could cause a runtime error if the `IsPossible` method doesn't properly filter all cases and the `ChangeType` fails.

```
public enum ValueParseTypes {
    Enum,
    DateTime,
    Int
}

public interface IDeviceValueTypedDeviceParameter<TValue> {
    string CodeName { get; }
    TValue Value { get; set; }
    Guid DeviceId { get; set; }
    ValueParseTypes ParseType { get; set; }

    bool IsPossibleValue(DeviceParameter aValue);
}

public abstract class DeviceValueTypedDeviceParameter<TValue> : IDeviceValueTypedDeviceParameter<TValue> {
    public string CodeName { get; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
    public Guid DeviceId { get; set; }
    public ValueParseTypes ParseType { get; set; }

    public DeviceValueTypedDeviceParameter(string codeName, ValueParseTypes parseType) {
        this.CodeName = codeName;
        this.ParseType = parseType;
    }

    public virtual bool IsPossibleValue(DeviceParameter aValue) => false;
}

public class ArmingStatusParameter : DeviceValueTypedDeviceParameter<ArmingStatuses> {
    public const string CODE_NAME = "ArmingStatus";

    public ArmingStatusParameter() : base(CODE_NAME, ValueParseTypes.Enum) {
    }

    static HashSet<string> ArmingStatusesNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ArmingStatuses)).ToHashSet();
    public override bool IsPossibleValue(DeviceParameter aValue) => ArmingStatusesNames.Contains(aValue.Value);
}

public enum ArmingStatuses {
    Unknown,
    Armed,
    Disarmed,
}

public class PoweredOnStatusParameter : DeviceValueTypedDeviceParameter<DateTime> {
    public const string CODE_NAME = "PoweredOn";

    public PoweredOnStatusParameter() : base(CODE_NAME, ValueParseTypes.DateTime) {
    }

    public override bool IsPossibleValue(DeviceParameter aValue) => DateTime.TryParse(aValue.Value, out _);
}

public class VoltageStatusParameter : DeviceValueTypedDeviceParameter<int> {
    public const string CODE_NAME = "PoweredOn";

    public VoltageStatusParameter() : base(CODE_NAME, ValueParseTypes.Int) {
    }

    public override bool IsPossibleValue(DeviceParameter aValue) => Int32.TryParse(aValue.Value, out _);
}

public static class DeviceValueTypedParameterConverter {
    public static bool TryConvert<TValue>(DeviceParameter inputParameter, IDeviceValueTypedDeviceParameter<TValue> outputParameter)
            where TValue : struct {
        if (inputParameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputParameter));
        else if (outputParameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outputParameter));

        bool result = false;
        if (outputParameter.IsPossibleValue(inputParameter)) {
            outputParameter.DeviceId = inputParameter.DeviceId;
            switch (outputParameter.ParseType) {
                case ValueParseTypes.Enum:
                    if (Enum.TryParse(inputParameter.Value, out TValue typedValue)) {
                        outputParameter.Value = typedValue;
                        result = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case ValueParseTypes.DateTime:
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(inputParameter.Value, out var dtValue)) {
                        outputParameter.Value = (TValue)Convert.ChangeType(dtValue, typeof(TValue));
                        result = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case ValueParseTypes.Int:
                    if (Int32.TryParse(inputParameter.Value, out var intValue)) {
                        outputParameter.Value = (TValue)Convert.ChangeType(intValue, typeof(TValue));
                        result = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like so:

```
var as_tv = new DeviceParameter() {
    Key = "testkey",
    DeviceId = new Guid(),
    Value = "Armed"
};

var asp = new ArmingStatusParameter();
if (DeviceValueTypedParameterConverter.TryConvert<ArmingStatuses>(as_tv, asp)) {
    // work with asp
}

var po_tv = new DeviceParameter() {
    Key = "testkey2",
    DeviceId = new Guid(),
    Value = "4/15/2019 17:36"
};

var pop = new PoweredOnStatusParameter();
if (DeviceValueTypedParameterConverter.TryConvert<DateTime>(po_tv, pop)) {
    // work with pop
}

var v_tv = new DeviceParameter() {
    Key = "testkey3",
    DeviceId = new Guid(),
    Value = "17"
};

var vp = new VoltageStatusParameter();
if (DeviceValueTypedParameterConverter.TryConvert<int>(v_tv, vp)) {
    // work with vp
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make implement based on those principles. The only thing that bothers me is that is TryConvert method needs to pass 2T's and the second T(TValue) can be passed wrongly. Is there any way to enforce the TValue to be "always correct" or remove it? That TValue is already present on the instance of DeviceValueTypedDeviceParameter<>. I think using an object, and getting the type at run time is a possibility, but I wanted to know if it was possible without reflection.

Comment: It isn't possible to have `T` be e.g. `ArmingStatusParameter` and figure out what `TValue` is supposed to be, but you can do the opposite (passing in only `TValue`) at the expense of having to create and pass-in the return value at the calling site. I have updated the code to do so.